# Email HTML 5 ainda deve ser feito dentro de tabelas?

Tags: html, css, envio-de-email

Ola,

Estou fazendo um **HTML** para **enviar por email** e, percebi que são **ultimamente** **feitos em tabelas**, mas, minha dúvida é se **isso ainda é necessário.**

Há algum tipo de riscos se eu **não fizer em tabelas** e o **css não for inline**, porque acabei de testar mandando para o Gmail e foi normalmente.

Obrigado

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O *Gmail* é apenas um cliente, existem vários como Thunderbird (Desktop), outlook.com (web), mail.yahoo.com (web) e cada sistema de email pode renderizar de uma forma, uma das maiores dores de cabeça dos desenvolvedores sem duvidas é o Outlook para Desktop.

Alguns detalhes importantes para obter uma melhor compatibilidade entre os clientes de e-mail:

- É necessário usar estilos inline, assim:

  ```
  <div style="color: #fc0;">Exemplo</div>
  ```
- No Outlook para desktop mesmo na versão mais recente não reconhece HTML5, então as tags devem ser as mesmas do HTML4.01, portanto ao invés de tags como `section` use somente `<div>`, `<span>`
- No outlook também é necessário declarar o DOCTYPE para HTML4 como:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
  ```

  ou:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  ```

  Lembre-se, para que ele funcione não pode haver nenhum tipo de espaço antes dele, nem quebras de linhas.
- Ainda no Outlook para Desktop é necessário eventualmente usar a tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` para melhor compatibilidade, já que ele usa o mesmo motor de renderização do HTML
- Emails as vezes desabilitam propriedades CSS como `position:;`, então preferencialmente nunca faça seus layouts baseados nisto
- Não use propriedades CSS3 avançadas para criar algum efeito especifico, é provável que não funcione em todos clientes de email
- Teste em todos cliente de email possíveis e se ainda tiver problemas, mesmo não sendo o indicado use sim tabelas.

### Alguns detalhes:

Tabelas e HTML5 não são duas coisas diferentes, sites feitos em HTML4 não são feitos em tabelas, na verdade tabelas era uma maneira de fazer layouts um "pouco errada" desde o começo, o objetivo delas é serem usadas para dados tabulares, tanto no HTML4 quanto no HTML5.

HTML5 somente inseriu tags e atributos novos e removeram outras e uma maneira mais simplificada e "unificada" de se criar HTML, antes tínhamos vários *DOCTYPES* e ainda tínhamos o XHTML, agora é praticamente tudo uma coisa só. Hoje o HTML5 suporta várias coisas (para não dizer tudo) que o XHTML suportava, basicamente ele pode ser HTML ou XHTML, bastando ajustar o `content-type`

### Dicas extras

- Não use `<link href="http://...">`, estilos externos serão bloqueados
- Não use `<script>`, isto não funciona de maneira alguma
- Crie uma versão alternativa da mensagem em formato de texto, isto ajuda leitores de email mais obsoletos que não conseguem ler html ou as vezes servem de "fallback", `PHPMailer` e `System.Net.Mail` já fazem isto (creio eu), manualmente a estrutura seria algo como:

  ```
  Mime-Version: 1.0
  Date: Sat, 03 Dec 2016 12:46:10 +0000
  Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
   boundary="----=MAIN"
  Subject: teste

  ------=MAIN
  Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
   boundary="----=INNER"


  ------=INNER
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
  Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

  Olá, mundo!

  ------=INNER
  Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
  Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
  <html>
  <head>
      <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div style="color: #fc0;">
      Olá, <strong>mundo</strong>!
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>

  ------=MAIN--
  ```

Comment: Então minha referencia é baseada no leitor que irá ler o e-mail, seja Gmail, Outlook e etc.. Correto? Caso sim, esses caras dão algum documento explicando o que eles aceitam?

Comment: Quis dizer referente o modo que eu devo escrever o HTML visando quem ira ler meu código, o recomendável seria fazer o mais adaptável possível para que não gere transtorno ao usuário.

Comment: @PedroSoares isso mesmo, pois o usuário não saberá o motivo e ainda existem muitos usuários de outlook para Desktop, o melhor é simplificar o HTML, usar HTML4, não usar efeitos CSS avançados, não usar fontes externas de letras, terá que usar imagens, usar a meta-tag edge e não usar a propriedade `position:;` do CSS.

Comment: Isso ai, agradeço pela resposta, garanto que irá ajudar muitas pessoas que vão querer tirar essa dúvida.

Answer (score 0):

Sem problema as pessoas normalmente fazem assim mais por compatibilidade, dependo do leitor de e-mail pode não ser compatível, alguns ainda mandam também a versão de texto puro caso o leitor não leia html.

lembrando só que o css como você falou precisa ser inline.

Deixo aqui também um [link](http://tableless.com.br/boas-praticas-para-e-mail-marketing/) para complementar minha resposta

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/90680)

Comment: mas o link é totalmente dispensável, uma vez que eu coloquei apenas como fonte alternativa...